# Gson JSON String Creation

Tags: jqgrid, gson

I am using JSON for displaying data in jqgrid. We were creating JSON string manually using string builder because we had to add html tags like div,button etc.. on each row.
    For example :

```
"userAction":">button class='className' onclick='javascript:functionname()' title='Title    here'>>img src='link' ></button>"
```

**NOTE : Using > insted of <**

```
className,onclick function, title, img src varies based on screens.
```

In each table we have around 25 columns out of which 2 or 3 are using html tags. Is it possible to use gson to achieve the same ?
which ever table there is no html tag required we are using Gson.tojson(List)

Answer (score 0):

It was achieved by using GSON serialiser as specifed in [Gson User Guide](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Serializer)